# React Router 4 - Server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am newbie to ReactJS and ReactRouter4, My routes are not working properly, any suggestions examples will be helpful.

below is my code,

```js
//main.js
class Main extends Component{

  render(){
    return (
        <div className="row navmargin">
          <div className="col-md-10">
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>

    <Route  path="/products" component={ProductsMain}/>

          </div>
          <div className="col-md-2">
            <p>other content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

class ProductsTab extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
          <h2>
                Products
            </h2>
            <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link  to={`${this.props.match.url}/all`} className ="nav-link">All</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link"  to={`${this.props.match.url}/brandwise`}>BrandWise</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div className="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                <Route exact path={this.props.match.url} component={AllProducts}/>
                <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/all`} component={AllProducts}/>
                <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/brandwise`} component={BrandwiseProducts}/>

            </div>
    )
  
  }

}

//productsmain.js
class ProductsMain extends Component{

  render(){
    return(
            <div>
            <Switch>
            <Route  path="/products" component={ProductsTab}/>
            <Route  path="/products/:id" component={ProductDetails}/>
     </Switch>
        
      
            </div>
    )
  }
}

ProductsMain = withRouter(ProductsMain);
export default ProductsMain;

//productdetails.js
class ProductDetails extends Component{

  render(){
    return(
            <div>
            <h2>
                Product Name
            </h2>
    <p>Details about project</p>
            </div>
    )
  }
}

ProductDetails = withRouter(ProductDetails);
export default ProductDetails;


//server side rendering
  const html = renderToString(
     <StaticRouter
       location={req.url}
       context={context}
     >
       <App/>
     </StaticRouter>
   );
```

Problem i am facing is 
1)http://localhost:3000/products/all 
When I navigate from main navigation this works fine with tabs and content, but when i hit above url directly in browser it remove my tabs and renders only AllProducts component content.
2)In AllProducts component i have a link item with url : http://localhost:3000/products/:p1234, when i click on link, url change but component wont render, so used withrouter also but no luck.

Comment: Does http://localhost:3000/products/p1234 (without the `:` in the link) work for you?

Comment: yes it worked even without :

Comment: For your main Component, why is <Switch> there?

Comment: I want product details content to be shown in same container, product details should not have tabs in the top. If i add inside productsmain switch it will be shown as child element.

Comment: That is incorrect, because Switch assumes that you are on the same path as root. You need to make another route like  <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/> in your main component. Follow the example they have in the docs here. If want to use switch, they must be on the same directory path. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i did tried like you suggested, but the problem is product details rendered as child under the main tabs. Since i added switch inside tab content section, above tabs are visible even in the case of product details

Comment: @Demon, edited the code, but problem now is that, all routes match to product/:id only

Comment: make sure that you if you want to make id optional add the product/:id? to the param, since you are using params, update with setState in the constructor of your components. Example:  if (this.state.productId != this.props.match.params.id) {update with setState}